# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException when migrating to v2 embedding

Tags: android, flutter

I have these errors `Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method METHOD NAME` when migrated example in plugin to match v2 embedding example.

Answer (score 0):

```
flutter clean & flutter pub get
```